# sqlmodel: adding an example to a Field()

Tags: sqlmodel

In pydantic we can add an example to Fields, such as:

`Field(default=None, example="A very nice Item")`

Which will then be displayed in the swagger API docs:

[image: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/img/tutorial/body-fields/image01.png]

How do we do this in sqlmodel? Adding the key example to the Field class in sqlmodel returns error:

> Field() got an unexpected keyword argument 'example'

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be accomplished using `schema_extra`:

> `Field(default=None, schema_extra={'example': "A very nice Item"})`

Can be found in code:

https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/blob/267cd42fb6c17b43a8edb738da1b689af6909300/sqlmodel/main.py#L119